# electron tray icon issue on windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows-10, electron, system-tray

I have built the electron app and now want to use **Tray** feature as mentioned [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md)

i am giving icon path which is located in the build folder at the base location as shown below

```
tray = new Tray(`file://${__dirname}/build/icon.ico`);
```

But this is throwing the following error
[image]

I want to know how to use the icon as its not mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this worked for me .Although the size of the icon has to be small to be shown

```
const { Tray, nativeImage } = require('electron');

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'build/icon-st.png');
mainWindow.tray = new Tray(nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath));
```

Comment: Can you please specify how small?

Comment: Please specify what size and also what type of icon. .ico? png?

Comment: @fsljfke I managed to get it to work by specifying size of 32x32 and a png file. I did it without the 'nativeImage.createFromPath()'. I just set the iconPath in new Tray

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a path issue with Windows. I would recommend using an absolute path using node's `path` module to correctly resolve the absolute path, like so:

```
const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'build/icon.ico');
tray = new Tray(iconPath);
```

There are several excellent comments on [this electron issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7657) that give various options for you.

Comment: Although the build is generated, but the icon isnt visible

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the issue by converting a png to base64, and used nativeImage.createFromDataURL to render accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Although the build is generated, but the icon isn't visible.

I had the same issue, a icon was not visible on windows 10 tray.

it happened because icon was not not visible in window's image viewer (damaged/corrupted icon).

I've downloaded a colored icon and retried and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have created method like below

```
function getAppPathToExecuteCommand() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
        return app.getAppPath();
    }
    else {
        if (platform.windows) {
            return path.dirname(app.getPath("exe"));
        } else if (platform.linux) {
            return process.resourcesPath;
        }
    }
}
```